# How I can show data of particular item of select box using datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I have all data when item_id is null :

```
var item_id = $("#ItemId").val();
jQuery('#stock_datatable').dataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    iDisplayLength: 25,
    search: {
        "search": item_id
    },
    ajax: {
            url: '{{ url("/stocklist-json") }}',
            data: {
                item_id: item_id
            },
        },
    columns: [
        { data: 'itemGroup', name: 'itemGroup' },
        { data: 'product', name: 'product' },
        { data: 'inward', name: 'inward' },
        { data: 'outward', name: 'outward' },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable:false }
    ]
});
```

Html :

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <label for="item">Item</label>
   <select name="ItemId" class="form-control" id="ItemId">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Item</option>
      @foreach($items as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->ProductName }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

When i code this for dropdown change event its says it can't reinitialize..
I want data of particular item when i select from this select box ??

Comment: do with jquery onchange event

Comment: paste your code in html only,

Comment: try with "destroy":true option in datatable